# Chinese visa required for Hong Kong visit?

Tags: visas, hong-kong

I’m an Indian national intending to visiting HK for 7 days as a tourist. The [HK immigration department](http://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/press/press-releases/20161212.html) has a pre-arrival registration for Indian nationals visiting HK to stay visa-free for not more than 14 days in HK. However a local travel agency told me that I would need a Chinese visa as well. Can anyone please confirm if this is indeed true? I don’t intend on visiting China during this travel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you don't need a Chinese visa to visit Hong Kong SAR, under the **[One country - two systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_country,_two_systems)** principle. China and Hong Kong SAR have separate visa/immigration policies and requirements.

From [the UK's foreign travel advice page for Hong Kong](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/hong-kong/entry-requirements):

> *Although Hong Kong is now part of the People’s Republic of China it remains a Special Administrative Region with its own immigration
>   controls. You can visit Hong Kong for up to 6 months without a visa.*

You do not need a Chinese visa unless you plan to also visit mainland China.